# Swift Rounding up Double

Tags: swift, double, rounding

I am trying to round a double up to a whole number,

```
var numberOfBottles = totalVolume / volumeEachBottles
```

for example `numberOfBottles = 275.0 / 250.0`
that would give me `1.1`, I need  it to round up to `2`

Comment: Do you want the Int 2 or the Double 2.0?

Answer (score 65):

Try:

```
var numberOfBottles = totalVolume / volumeEachBottles
numberOfBottles.rounded(.up)
```

or

```
numberOfBottles.rounded(.down)
```

Answer (score 24):

There is a built-in global function called `ceil` which does exactly this:

```
var numberOfBottles = ceil(totalVolume/volumeEachBottles)
```

This returns `2`, as a `Double`.

[image]

`ceil` is actually declared in `math.h` and documented [here in the OS X man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ceil.3.html).  It is almost certainly more efficient than any other approach.

Even if you need an `Int` as your final result, I would start by calculating `ceil` like this, and then using the `Int` constructor on the result of the `ceil` calculation.

Comment: It's not built-in, you have to `import Foundation` to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

var numberOfBottles = 275.0 / 250.0
var rounded = ceil(numberOfBottles)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for rounding it to a whole number and use it in the UI then this can be useful. Just add this as the last thing in your file or in a own file:

```
extension Double {
func roundToInt() -> Int{
    return Int(Darwin.round(self))
}
```

}

And use it like this if you like to have it in a textlabel:

```
currentTemp.text = "\(weatherData.tempCelsius.roundToInt())"
```

Or print it as an Int:

```
print(weatherData.tempCelsius.roundToInt())
```

Comment: This blows up when the double is greater than maxint